# How to run Ubilinux / u-boot under qemu (x86)

Tags: embedded, qemu, u-boot, x86

I wish to test Ubilinux (http://www.emutexlabs.com/ubilinux) before flashing it onto my Intel Edison board, which currently has Yocto on it.

I am able to emulate Yocto for Edison with qemu, running of a kernel and a filesystem image: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html#setting-up-the-environment-and-starting-the-qemu-emulator

How do I do the same for Ubilinux? The download from the emutexlabs contains a script to flash the Edison, and multiple image files. I hoping I could do something like follows, but no luck:

```
runqemu qmeux86 u-boot-edison.bin edison-image-edison.ext4
```

or perhaps

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel u-boot-edison.img edison-image-edison.ext4 -option-rom edison-image-edison.hddimg
```

I'm new to embedded systems and low-level OS stuff, so a clear explanation of what the kernel, initrd, and filesystem images are for Ubilinux would be great. Any additional explanation of how u-boot works (with qemu) would also be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but interested in Edison as well. Can you share the the exact command line you use to launch the Yocto in QEMU? Maybe we can work something from there.

Comment: @AtillaFiliz, for latest and greatest stuff for Intel Edison better to look here: https://github.com/edison-fw (and wiki: https://htot.github.io/meta-intel-edison/)